# Why do you have to press ALT+` twice to switch windows within an application?

Tags: application-switcher

ALT+` switches windows within a running application.

But I notice that you actually have to press this key combo twice to switch to the next window. Pressing it once only displays the application's open windows (within the current workspace).

Why is this? Why isn't a single ALT+` sufficient to switch windows?

After all, ALT+Tab behaves in the expected way when you want to switch between applications.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you're talking about. Make sure you've got your system updated. Some bugs about window switching with Alt+` were squashed in Unity 5.16.0.

Comment: You're right. This was fixed in a recent update.

Comment: This actually answered a question I was about to ask: how to switch windows within an application!